# Find the velocity vector in the form of polar coordinates

Tags: derivatives, vectors, physics, partial-derivative

Lets say for an object doing a projectile motion, in order to find the velocity vector in the function of t;

R is constant.

$$\vec r(t) = R\hat r + \theta (t) \hat \theta \\
\vec V(t) = \frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt} \\
\vec V(t) = 0\hat r + \theta '(t) \hat \theta \\
\vec V(t) = \theta '(t) \hat \theta$$,which is not true.

So, where is the mistake in this calculation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $R$ may not be constant. Besides, there is no $\hat{\theta}$ component of $\vec{r}$ in polar coordinates.

The position of the particle at time $t$ is specified by $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ through

$$\vec{r}(t)=r(t)\hat{r}\left(r(t),\theta(t)\right).$$

Note that $\hat{r}$ is a function of $t$ through
$$\hat{r}\left(r(t),\theta(t)\right)$$

$$\vec{v}(t)=\frac{dr}{dt}\hat{r}(t)+r(t)\frac{d\hat{r}}{dt}$$
$$=\dot{r}(t)\hat{r}(t)+r(t)\left(\frac{\partial \hat{r}}{\partial r}\dot{r}+\frac{\partial \hat{r}}{\partial \theta}\dot{\theta}\right)$$
Since
$$\frac{\partial \hat{r}}{\partial r}=\vec{0}, \frac{\partial \hat{r}}{\partial \theta}=\hat{\theta}$$
we have
$$\vec{v}(t)=\dot{r}(t)\hat{r}(t)+r(t)\dot{\theta}(t)\hat{\theta}(t)$$

Comment: I couldn't understand how you took the derivative of $\hat r(t)$ respect to t.

Comment: By chain rule of $\hat{r}(r(t),\theta(t))$.

Comment: could you give the definition of $\hat r$, because I didn't understand how $\hat r$ can carry $r(t)$ information

Comment: I understand the calculations, there is no problem, but I still don't get it how a unit vector can carry $r(t)$ information.

Comment: By the way, what is the problem in my $\vec r $ definition ?

Comment: $\hat{r}$ is the radial unit vector at the position of the particle at time $t$, so it depends on $t$. In your definition of $\vec{r}(t)$, first $R$ should depend on $t$, and second, there are many different $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ located at different points, which ones are you talking about?

Comment: I'm not talking about a specific $\hat r$ or $\hat \theta$, I'm talking about generally how $\hat r$ can depend on $r(t)$ ?

Comment: In other words, how can the information that the distance from the origin of a particle affect the direction ?

Comment: You should allow $\hat{r}$ to depend on $\theta(t)$ as well, not only $r(t)$.

Comment: I know that, but I didn't mention it because it is the obvious part.

Comment: But you have not differentiated your $\hat{r}$. You treated it as a constant vector.

Comment: you are right, I thought using $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ can separate two information, but since the direction of $\hat r$ is not constant, it changes according to $\theta$, but there is still the same problem.How can $\hat r$ depends on $r(t)$ ?

Comment: It does not, so I said $\frac{\partial \hat{r}}{\partial r}=\vec{0}$.

Comment: then why are you including as a parameter for $\hat r$ ?

Comment: For general coordinate system, the unit vectors may depend on ALL parameters. You are right that $\hat{r}$ does not depend on $r$ for polar coordinates. So if you like you just omit it from the beginning. But it does not make any difference.